# jquery sql .NET - trying to create a delete button that can remove ID's from server

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

So I have a program that generates ID's within a database using jquery and .NET. I am trying to create a delete button so that when the user gets to this section, all they have to do is select the radial button in which the ID is and click the delete button to remove it, but I am unsure of how to do this. I have read that using some sort of ajax call would work but am unfamiliar with the functionality of it. Here is what I have so far:

```
    function UserSelection(Type_ID) {
        var Type_Value = "";

        if (Type_ID == 1)
            Type_Value = "html";
        else if (Type_ID == 2)
            Type_Value = "doc"
        else if (Type_ID == 3)
            Type_Value = "src"

        $('#userselectionmade').dialog({
            width: 700,
            height: 400,
            title: 'Generate Document',
            buttons: {
                'Edit Document': function () {
                    var documentID = $('#<%= rblUserDocument.ClientID %>').children().children().children().find("input:checked").val(); 
                    window.location = "AddEditDocument.aspx?action=Edit&documentID=" + documentID + "";
                },
                'Delete Document': function (){
                    var documentID = $('#<%= rblUserDocument.ClientID %>').children().children().children().find("input:checked").val();
                    window.location = "AddEditDocument.aspx?action=Edit&documentID=" + documentID + "";

                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        })

        return false;
    }
```

The 'Delete Document' button is the one I am having trouble with. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help get you started..

Something like this would make the ajax call to your AddEditDocument.aspx page where you would provide the code to delete the document from the database.

```
'Delete Document': function (){
    var documentID = $('#<%= rblUserDocument.ClientID %>').children().children().children().find("input:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "AddEditDocument.aspx",
      type: "get",
      data: {action: "Delete", documentID: documentID},
      success: function(){
         alert("Document ID# " + documentID + " has been deleted.");
         // Then maybe remove the document HTML div from page.
         // $('#Div_of_document').remove(); 
      },
      error:function(){
        alert("failure");
      }
   });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

try the code below where you can save radiobutton id in some variable and later use this radio button ID to find closest row(tr) and remove it.

```
'Delete Document': function (){

    var rb = $('#<%= rblUserDocument.ClientID %>').children().children().children().find("input:checked");

    var documentID = $(rb).val();
    var rbID = $(rb).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
      url: "AddEditDocument.aspx",
      type: "get",
      data: {action: "Delete", documentID: documentID},
      success: function(){
         alert("Document ID# " + documentID + " has been deleted.");

//remove whole tr        
 $('#'+rbID ).closest('tr').remove();

      },
      error:function(){
        alert("failure");
      }
   });
},
```

Comment: not sure what +ebID is referring to. But I tried using different references to variables with this and couldn't make it work.

Comment: sorry was a typo, just fixed. it is rbID

Comment: when I use this, it is saying rb is not defined from the line: var rbID = $(rb).attr('id');

Comment: not aware of your markup but this line should init rb  "var rb = $('#<%= rblUserDocument.ClientID %>').children().children().children().find("input:checked");"