# follow up delete questions

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I had started a delete question here [jquery sql .NET - trying to create a delete button that can remove ID's from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662186/jquery-sql-net-trying-to-create-a-delete-button-that-can-remove-ids-from-ser) and I have a follow up to this question. I can delete within the interface using whatever elements (td, id's), my question is how to I delete a specific element without deleting everything. Let me give you an example:

Here is the jQuery:

```
                'Delete': function (){
                    var documentID = $('#<%= rblUserDocument.ClientID %>').children().children().children().find("input:checked").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "AddEditDocument.aspx",
                        type: "get",
                        data: { action: "Delete", documentID: documentID },
                        success: function () {
                            alert("Document ID# " + documentID + "has been deleted");
                            $('#CertainID_1').remove();
                            $('label').remove();
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("failure");
                        }
                    });
                },
```

The information is stored in a table, so there is  tags where each  tag holds an ID and a . Each ID has different name but they are numbered, example: CertainID_1, CertainID_2, CertainID_3 and so on. Since the ajax is identifying all ID's and label's (if I use what is currently in the code now $('label').remove();, how do I get it to identify the certain ID or label that the user clicks on? Currently I can only put a generalized delete in which I don't want it to delete all labels or all ID's within the table.

It looks like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input id="CertainID_1" type="radio" value="1" name="CertainID_1">
         <label for="CertainID_1>working</label>
      </td>
   </tr>
      <td>
         <input id="CertainID_2" type="radio" value="1" name="CertainID_2">
         <label for="CertainID_2>working</label>
      </td>
   </tr>
      <td>
         <input id="CertainID_2" type="radio" value="1" name="CertainID_2">
         <label for="CertainID_2>working</label>
      </td>
   </tr>
      <td>
         <input id="CertainID_2" type="radio" value="1" name="CertainID_2">
         <label for="CertainID_2>working</label>
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: why don't you pass parent element ID in ajax call and on success return the same id so that you can delete it?

Comment: how would I go about doing that though?

Comment: the same way you have passed other parameters  data: { action: "Delete", documentID: documentID },

Comment: Please also share sample html so that we know the html hierarchy

Comment: is the html markup generated by rblUserDocument?

Comment: the userdocument is what is genereated when the function runs

Comment: the table is where the jquery is reading to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43442/discussion-between-shoaib-shaikh-and-keith)

Comment: please share the js and html in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TdNnC/ here is the information

Comment: What about a loop array that goes through each ID and gets the ID, then upon clicking the delete button delete's that ID?

Comment: please check the answer in your earlier question